# Cannot make notify() to work with Bouncing Balls using Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use one thread to control bouncing balls. I can add balls, delete balls, suspend the movement but when i try to resume the movement of bouncing balls, notify()/notifyAll() is not working. I want only one thread to control the movement of balls that are being added in a List. I would appreciate a simple explanation as I am a complete novice. Here is the code:

```
 ************************************************
 public class BounceBallApp extends JApplet {
 public BounceBallApp() {
 add(new BallControl());
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     BounceBallApp applet = new BounceBallApp();
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
     frame.add(applet); //new line added as per the reference
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setTitle("Assig_1_Base");
     frame.add(applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frame.setSize(400, 320);
     frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
***************************************************************
 public class BallControl extends JPanel {

private BallPanel ballPanel = new BallPanel();
private JButton jbtSuspend = new JButton("Suspend");
private JButton jbtResume = new JButton("Resume");
private JScrollBar jsbDelay = new JScrollBar();
private JButton jbtAddBall = new JButton("+1");
private JButton jbtDeleteBall = new JButton("-1");

    public BallControl() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(jbtSuspend);
    panel.add(jbtResume);
    panel.add(jbtAddBall);
    panel.add(jbtDeleteBall);
    ballPanel.add();


   ballPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(Color.red));
   jsbDelay.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
   ballPanel.setDelay(jsbDelay.getMaximum());
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   add(jsbDelay, BorderLayout.NORTH);
   add(ballPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  // Register listeners
   jbtSuspend.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ballPanel.suspend();
     }
    });
  jbtResume.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       ballPanel.resume();
    }
   });

  jbtAddBall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ballPanel.add();
    }
  });
  jbtDeleteBall.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      ballPanel.delete();
    }
  });
 jsbDelay.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
   @Override
   public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
    ballPanel.setDelay(jsbDelay.getMaximum() - e.getValue());
  }
 });
}
```

}

---

```
public class BallPanel extends JPanel {

  private int delay = 10;   
  private List<Ball> ballsArray = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
  //protected List<Ball> ballsArray = new ArrayList<>();
  private int radius = 5; 
  boolean threadSuspended = false;

  public BallPanel() {
    start();
  }

  protected void start(){
   Thread t;
     t = new Thread(){
        @Override
         public void run(){
            System.out.println("*************");
             while (true){
                repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                       synchronized(this){
                        if (threadSuspended==true) {wait();}
                       }
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }
   };

    t.start();
 }

 @Override
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Ball ball : ballsArray){

        g.setColor(ball.color);

                if (ball.x < 0 || ball.x > getWidth()) 
                  ball.dx *= -1;
        if (ball.y < 0 || ball.y > getHeight()) 
          ball.dy *= -1;

                ball.x += ball.dx;
        ball.y += ball.dy;
        g.fillOval(ball.x - radius, ball.y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
    }   
}

public synchronized void suspend() {
  threadSuspended = true;
}

public synchronized void resume() {
  threadSuspended = false;
  notify();
}

public void setDelay(int delay) {
  this.delay = delay;
}
public void add(){
  if (threadSuspended==false)  ballsArray.add(new Ball());
}

public void delete(){
  if (ballsArray.size() > 0 && threadSuspended==false)
      ballsArray.remove(ballsArray.size() - 1); // Remove the last ball

 }
}

**************************************************
public class Ball  {

 int x = 0; 
 int y = 0;
 int dx = 2;
 int dy = 2;
 Color color = new Color(random(255),random(255),random(255));

     public static int random(int maxRange) {
     return (int) Math.round((Math.random() * maxRange));
  }

}
```

---

Comment: Anyone please as I am completely frustrated with this problem. Please help!!!

Comment: I think most won't read through all that code. Only post the relevant parts. What have you tried? Where is the error? [Don't expect us to think for you.](http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/The_Guru_Myth)

Comment: Are you sure that the code is passing through the necessary places? Maybe inserting a few `System.out.println()` messages both at the `resume()` method and also the place where you are doing the `wait()`, both before it and after it, so that you know what's happening, when the thread is stopping to wait and whether it receiving the notification.

Comment: @Adam Arnold Trying to add bouncing balls in a frame using List. There are two buttons "Suspend" and "Resume" setting a boolean flag. Suspend makes the thread to go in wait() state but when I use the "Resume" button that is resetting the boolean flag is not notifying the Thread that is in wait state.

Comment: @jbx resume() is just resetting the boolean flag and using notify() method. But the Balls in the frame remain in the hang state. Also I tried using System.out.println() in various places and you are right that notify() in the resume() does not have any effect on the run() in start(). What do I do? What logic should I change here?

Comment: @Adam Arnold The whole code is a working code except for the resume(). I can't get my head around how to notify() the thread that is in the hang state.

Comment: @CompleteIdiot check the answer by @MadProgrammer, its most probably as he is saying. You are doing `wait()` on the instance of `Thread` while you are doing `notify()` on the instance of `BallPanel`. You are notifying the wrong object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a "context" issue...

You declare the `Thread` within the context of the `BallPane`...

So, when you call `wait()`, you are actually calling `wait()` on `t`

```
Thread t;
t = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        /*...*/
        // this = t
        synchronized(this){
            // This is the same as saying
            // this.wait() or t.wait();
            if (threadSuspended==true) {wait();}
        }
    }
};
```

But when you call `notify`, you are calling `BallPane`'s `notify` method...

```
public synchronized void resume() {
    threadSuspended = false;
    // This is the same as this.notify or BallPane.this.notify()
    notify();
}
```

So, `t` is waiting on `t`'s monitor lock and you call `BallPane`'s notify on it's monitor lock...meaning `t` will never be notified.

It would be better if you used a shared lock instead...

```
public class BallPanel extends JPanel {
    protected static final Object SUSPEND_LOCK = new Object();

    /*...*/

    Thread t;
    t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            /*...*/
            synchronized(SUSPEND_LOCK ){
                if (threadSuspended==true) {SUSPEND_LOCK.wait();}
            }
        }
    };

    /*...*/

    public void resume() {
        synchronized(SUSPEND_LOCK){
            threadSuspended = false;
            SUSPEND_LOCK.notify();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer.. Thank you most kindly. IT is working perfect now. "I should have wished for a big Tatts win " as when I was posting my question I was hoping you would answer my post & you did :). Your answers regarding using one thread as opposed to multiple threads helped me a lot. But looking at my code - do you think this is really bad way of doing it?

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a `javax.swing.Timer` as you can stop and restart them easily, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right :). I have the same code with timer which is working perfectly. But wanted to experiment with this.

Comment: @CompleteIdiot By the way, instead of creating an anonymous class like that, you could have also simply made `BallPanel` extend `Runnable`, and moved the `run()` method outside as a method of `BallPanel`, which would have made the `this.wait()` work. The `start()` method would then do `Thread t = new Thread(this); t.start();`. This would remove the need for the `SUSPEND_LOCK` object.

Comment: @jbx Is the functionality exactly the same? What is the drawback/advantage of these two approaches? And also, i would like to know your opinion on the code that i tried. How can I improve it? And yes implementing Runnable revokes the need for lock object. I tried your suggestion and ran the code successfully

Comment: @CompleteIdiot It is generally considered good proactive to implement Runnable over extending Thread

Comment: @CompleteIdiot Well both alternatives are available and useful in their own right. If you want to simplify the code and avoid lots of unneeded nesting you could adopt the `Runnable` implementation. Sometimes you need more different `Runnable` implementations in which case the approach suggested by MadProgrammer is more suitable.  In OOP you have to think a lot in terms of roles and responsibilities. You should ask, is my `BallPanel` directly 'responsible' for this (in which case it implements `Runnable` itself) or is it delegating to something else?

Comment: Also, as MadProgrammer said, it is generally considered better practice to implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`, for the simple reason that your object might need to extend something else, and thus since in Java you can only extend one class, by extending `Thread` you would be wasting this chance. In your case however you are implementing an anonymous class which extends Thread, which is different, you are delegating. This approach is usually used more in event handlers (for example having multiple buttons in a Swing interface with each one having a different action).